# "I don't want him knowing..." vs. "I don't want him to know... "

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

There is some dialogue in a movie I saw:

> I don't want him *knowing* about this.

I always thought it was

> I don't want him *to know* about this.

I've been confused for days. What is the difference between them, if any?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. You might be interested in [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), our sister site, which is a good site for basic English questions. This construction (I don't want him knowing/finding out/leaving too soon/etc.) is a common one, especially in spoken English. It means the same thing as *to know*/etc. It doesn't always work and it doesn't always sound natural. I think it's more common with negatives than positives (One wouldn't say, *I want him knowing about this*).

Comment: It is not, in my view, a particularly elegant way of speaking, though you will hear the present participle used a lot, particularly in the UK among regional speakers, to replace both the infinitive (as in this case) or more often the past participle. E.g. a waiter might say 'How would you like your steak cooking?', where Received English would say 'How would you like it cooked?'.

Comment: _Want_ can take either a gerund or an infinitive complement. The construct _`A` want `B` `Verb`-ing_ is quite common, though only with an accusative subject, not a genitive one. In other words, **I don't want his knowing about this* is right out, but *I don't want him knowing about this* is just fine, in fact as likely as the infinitive.

Comment: Differences in meaning? Well, they amount to the same thing in the end, but they get there by different routes. The infinitive tends to refer to the **event** of his coming to know (i.e, learning) about this, while the gerund tends to refer to the **state** of his knowing about this. The infinitive is inchoative and the gerund is the result state. Since every nonpermanent state has a beginning, and every change of state has a result state, they both refer to the same unwanted outcome.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is subtle.

"I don't want him to know about Xyz" means you'd rather he not *acquire knowledge* about Xyz while "I don't want him knowing about Xyz" means you'd rather he not *possess knowledge* about Xyz.

But you will possess knowledge if and only if you acquire it (and you don't forget it).  A difference that doesn't make a difference isn't really a difference.

Either form is acceptable and in common use.